# Why is Ruby's Date class automatically loaded but DateTime is not?

Tags: ruby

Using IRB, why are the Date & Time classes automatically loaded, but DateTime is not? I have to `require 'date'`, this does not make sense to me because I thought that both Date and DateTime were using the standard library `'date'`?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > Date
 => Date
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > Time
 => Time
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > DateTime
NameError: uninitialized constant Object::DateTime
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/kamilski81/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > require 'date'
 => true
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :005 > require 'date'
 => false
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :006 > DateTime
 => DateTime
```

Comment: In 1.9.3p125 `Date` is not loaded automatically.

Comment: `Date` has never been loaded automatically, you, or more likely `irb`, probably loads it, or loads something that in turn loads it.

Comment: `Date` is not really loaded automatically, take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11633934/52499).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a little more curious, I tried:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts DateTime.class'
-e:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Object::DateTime (NameError)
[~, kamilski81@mac]
$ ruby -e 'puts Date.class'
-e:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Object::Date (NameError)
$ ruby -e 'puts Time.class'
Class
```

So it makes me think that it's an irb issue that automatically loads 'date'.

Comment: Please append this to your original question and delete this answer.

Answer (score 47):

In IRB, include this line: `require 'date'` then you will be able to use DateTime.

```
irb(main):000:0> DateTime.class
NameError: uninitialized constant DateTime
        from (irb):0
        from /path/to/ruby/irb:12:in '(main)'
irb(main):001:0> require 'date'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> DateTime.class
=> Class
```

Answer (score 4):

Worked for me when first initializing with `require 'date'`.