# Why does Date exist in Ruby before it is required?

Tags: ruby, date

In Ruby, I'd expect that a class which has not been required would raise an "uninitialized constant" error. This is the case with `CSV`, for instance.

However, `Date` behaves strangely: it is available, but apparently does not work, until it is required.

```
~: irb                                                                                             
>> Date.new(2012,7,24)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(3 for 0)
>> require 'date'
=> true
>> Date.new(2012,7,24)
=> #<Date: 2012-07-24 ((2456133j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

What explains this behavior?

Comment: +1, always bugged me. you'll notice the slight difference when calling `Date.ancestors` before and after the `require`. Also, calling `Date.new` (no args) before requiring seems to return a pretty generic object with no specific methods or instance variables. Guess it's somehow needed by the core classes ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that `date` doesn't come from `irb`, but from `rubygems`, specifically [the file](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/lib/rubygems/specification.rb#L13) where `Gem::Specification` is defined:

```
class Date; end # for ruby_code if date.rb wasn't required
```

I believe they needed *any* `Date` class defined so that the interpreter doesn't complain further down in the `Specification` class.

Comment: This seems like the more likely correct answer since the same behavior can be observed in pry, and nobody has yet pointed to the class definition in the irb source.  Thanks!

Comment: One should probably point out, that [`rubygems` is loaded automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21531923/52499).

Answer (score 5):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704969/why-is-rubys-date-class-automatically-loaded-but-datetime-is-not). `irb` loads a `Date` class by default, but Ruby itself doesn't (try e.g. `puts Date.new` in a file).

It seems that the `Date` class that `irb` loads is different to the distribution class, as you have pointed out. Furthermore this only seems to be the case in Ruby 1.9 -- if I try it in 1.8, I get the same class methods before and after the require.

Comment: That is truly strange. I wish irb would load the true Date class if it needs one for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer: it seems that the incomplete `Date` class [comes from irb, not from ruby.](http://www.whynotwiki.com/Ruby_/_Dates_and_times#Caveat%3a_you_may_need_to_require_certain_date_classes_for_certain_Date.2FTime_features)