# which ruby modules are loaded by default?

Tags: ruby

Until just recently, I thought that all standard modules (those one can see on http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/) aren't loaded by default. That is, you must require each and every one you're going to use. But it turns out some of them are indeed loaded, judging from contents of `$LOADED_FEATURES`:

```
$ ruby -rpp -e 'p $LOADED_FEATURES'
["enumerator.so",
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so",
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so",
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb",
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb",
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb",
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb",
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb",
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb",
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb",
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/platform.rb",
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb",
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb",
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb",                                                                                          
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb",
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb",
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/prettyprint.rb",
 "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pp.rb"]
```

So I wonder what is the reason and can I influence this in any way?

**UPD** output without requiring `pp`

```
$ ruby -e 'p $LOADED_FEATURES'
["enumerator.so", "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so", "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so", "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb", "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb", "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb", "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb", "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb", "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb", "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb", "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/platform.rb", "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb", "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb", "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb", "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb", "/home/yuri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb"]
```

Comment: you required `pp` already, can you try to print without requiring `pp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only library I see loaded there is RubyGems, and that was indeed added to Ruby in 1.9.0.

BTW: you don't `require` `module`s, you `require` files.

Comment: So all those files are loaded as a result of loading `rubygems.rb`? Do you know why is it loaded by default?