# Why can I use the Date class without requiring 'date'?

Tags: ruby, date, time

I recently was doing an exercism.io exercise to determine a person's gigagsecond anniversary, given her/his birthday.  [If you want, you can nitpick me here](http://exercism.io/submissions/78a663b0cbd094daa64f7460).

While doing this exercise, I discovered in irb that I get different results if I did *not* `require 'date'`.
[image]

vs using `require 'date'`.

[image]

Further I tried the same in [repl.it](http://repl.it/), and get an error if I try to use `Date` without `require 'Date'`.

[image]

I was able to find some responses to the 'uninitialized constant' error ([Why is Ruby's Date class automatically loaded but DateTime is not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704969/why-is-rubys-date-class-automatically-loaded-but-datetime-is-not) and [Why does Date exist in Ruby before it is required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704969/why-is-rubys-date-class-automatically-loaded-but-datetime-is-not).) which led me down the path of perhaps versioning is the culprit; but, I couldn't find any overwhelmingly definitive response.

I am using: Ruby 2.1.3, irb 0.9.6 (which I believe uses Ruby 2.0.0) and repl.it is using Ruby 1.8.7(beta).

So, is this a version thing? ...an irb vs Ruby thing? ...a Date class in the standard library + Date module thing?  Or simply that I'm just a n00b?

Lastly I messed around a bit more with the date objects in irb and got an error 'Maybe IRB bug!'[image]

(FWIW, I did the same thing for 'time' in irb but this time, got the same result regardless if I required 'time'.)
[image]

Comment: I get a not found error in Ruby 1.9.3 (not IRB), but it works in Ruby 2.0.0-p0 (Not IRB)

Comment: Don't paste screen captures, but type the code. It is hard to see. We will judge you as a lazy person.

Comment: ...and harder to copy for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rubygems (which is required by default) [defines a empty, non-functioning `Date` class](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_4/lib/rubygems/specification.rb#L18-L20) in versions earlier than 2.4.0 (Rubygems version, not Ruby). This has been [fixed recently](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/948) (also see the [Ruby bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9890)). The version of Rubygems with the fix will likely be included in Ruby 2.2.

Comment: Thanks @matt! I [updated my version of Rubygems](https://rubygems.org/pages/download) to the most current version 2.4.2.  And tested in irb without `require 'date'`:

    `2.1.3 :001 > date = Date.new`
    `NameError: uninitialized constant Date`

...and with:      
    `2.1.3 :002 > require 'date' => true`
    `2.1.3 :003 > date = Date.new => #<Date: -4712-01-01 ((0j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`

Answer (score 0):

This is not an IRB issue. At least in Ruby 2.1, `require 'date'` loads both the [Date](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) and [DateTime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/xmlrpc/rdoc/XMLRPC/DateTime.html) classes. In fact, the second line of the `Date` doc states, "'date' provides two classes Date and DateTime."

File `t.rb`:

```
require 'date'
p DateTime.new(2014,01,01,01,01,01).to_time
```

Carys-MacBook-Pro:ruby_src Cary$ ruby "t.rb"

```
#=> 2013-12-31 17:01:01 -0800
```

It appears to also load the [Time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Time.html) class as well:

```
p Date.today.to_time.to_a.join(' ')
#=>  "0 0 0 29 10 2014 3 302 true PDT"
```

though I suppose it could be that `to_time` loads `Time`. Can someone clarify this last point?